# Select statement with variables, but not work

Tags: php, mysql

i try to select statement with variable, but not work maybe i miss something.

```
<!--Get data from user--> 
    <?php while ($row_settings = mysql_fetch_array($rs_settings4)) {
            $get_id_friend=$row_settings['friend_id'];
    } ?>
<!--Get data from user--> 


  <div id="wrap-box"><!--Loop-box-->
<?php $results  = mysql_query("select * from users where id='$get_id_friend'");  ?>  
  <?php while ($row_friend_loop = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {?>
        <div class="img">
            <img src="<?php echo $row_friend_loop['img']; ?>" width="49"/>
        </div>

        <div id="request">
            <div class="name">
            <p><?php echo $row_friend_loop['user_name']; ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="btn">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/btn-confirm.jpg" class="hover" /></a><a href="#">
            <img src="images/btn-ignore.jpg" class="hover" /></a>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
       <?php } ?><!--Loop-box-->
```

i try to change from

```
where id='$get_id_friend'");
```

to

```
where id='.$get_id_friend.'");
```

but still not work,
sorry i'm still newbie here

first i want get id from table friend, and if id from table friend is related with table user , all data with related id will be loop .

Comment: you can't post a bunch of code and say that it doesn't work, you've to explain in detail what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: In your first while loop you're overwriting $get_id_friend at each passage, might be that? also, if ID is numeric, check against that (intval($get_id_friend), for. ex.)

Comment: Most likely the problem is that the second query is outside the while loop, in which $get_id_friend is defined, so it's executed only for the last value of $get_id_friend. But please define "not work", - what is the expected and what is the actual output?

Comment: ok. i want get data from table user, and loop all data from id $get_id_friend', this will loop all data.

Comment: oh..that correct @Darhazer the first loop is the problem..i should close the tag at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you read up on sql injection and the PDO library. Also, I have a feeling you do not have a very efficient database structure.

I'm just guessing on your motive and database here, but you should start with something like this:

```
TABLE friends
int id PRIMARY
int user_id
int friend_id

TABLE users
int user_id
VARCHAR(64) img
VARCHAR(24) user_name
```

This way, one table holds all the user information, and the second table holds all the 'friend' data. The correct way to access this info would be to use prepared statements and then you can loop through the resulting array, ie: the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT 
           friends.friend_id AS friend_id,
           users.img AS friend_img,
           users.user_name AS friend_user_name,
        FROM friends
        LEFT JOIN users ON (friend.user_id = users.user_id)
        WHERE friend.user_id = :user_id";
$sth = PDO->prepare($q);
$sth->bindParam(":user_id",$user_id_to_get_friends_for);

try{
     $sth->execute();
     $friends = $sth->fetchAll();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
     //  Do something with the error
}

// Now loop through the array
foreach($friends as $f) {
     echo "<td><img src='".$f['friend_img']."' alt='' />".$f['friend_user_name']."</td>";
}
```

Now, this is oversimplified i'm sure, but if you follow this format, and do a little research on the functions i'm using here (namely LEFT JOIN and PDO stuff), you should be off to a good start.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: it is difficult for me to understand the "JOIN Statement" I'm still beginner,btw this is good direction.

Comment: @ruslyrossi No problem! We are all learning, and i'm glad I can help.

the "JOIN" function is essentially 'joining' two or more tables together on common elements. For example, we are saying here (in human terms) "Join friends with users wherever the user id's match between the tables". That way, the query actually returns one dataset that is created from two 'joined' tables. In more complex queries, you might 'join' many different tables together, and at the end, you end up with one table that contains only the information you need.

Answer (score -1):

Syntactically there's absolutely no difference in how your two versions of building the `where` clause work - if neither works, then `$get_id_friend` is not set properly. Neither of your queries have any error handling, and you don't show the query string for the initial query, only how you fetch data from it.

A proper minimalist 'safe' query structure is:

```
$sql = "SELECT ...";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error . "<br />$sql");
}
```

Since your last comment indicates you're looping over multiple user records and displaying data on those users, you'd be better of using a single joined query, rather than an "outer" query that causes repeated inner queries.

Something like this:

```
SELECT friends.img, friends.user_name
FROM users AS friends
LEFT JOIN users ON users.friend_id = users.id
WHERE users = $userID;
```

That's just a guess, since we have very little information about your table structure. But basically: given some userID, fetch the images and user_names of all their friends. Now you've reduced your code to:

```
$sql = "select query from above";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error() . "<br />$sql");
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    ... your html stuff as before ...
}
```

One loop, one query, less fuss and muss.

Comment: wow..i learn something today..thanks..maybe i need more practice and practice

Comment: This code `$sql = "SELECT ...";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error . "<br />$sql");
}` is fine when testing, but will leave you wide open to hacking, because you've just listed your exact queries for all the world to see if an error occurs; **never use code like this in production**

Comment: -1 for not quoting injected $vars. This leaves you wide open to SQL-injection and syntax errors if the id is not guaranteed to be numeric. Nowhere in the OP's or your code is this enforced.